# Unable save DataFrame to Phoenix

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

When I try the below code in Spark:

```
jdbcDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .options(Map("table" -> "DC_PATIENT", "zkUrl" -> "hadoop001:2181"))
      .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").save()
```

It throws the following exception :

```
 error: not found: value SaveMode
```

Am I missing any JARs? `jdbcDF` is a correct dataframe.

Environment:

> - Scala 2.11.8
> - Spark 2.2.0
> - Phoenix apache-phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.1

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode`

Comment: hey,man ,I tried yours,but it still can't work.. I've already import  org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.phoenix.spark._   it showed me "save is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame "